# Cassandra cluster creating a schema appears to bring all nodes down?

Tags: cassandra, schema, cluster-computing, nodes, cql

So I'm attempting to create a test a cassandra cluster (3 nodes). I've set up 3 nodes using Cassandra 1.2.19, all on the same datacenter. On each node I've edited the cassandra.yaml file, and the cassandra-topology.proeperties file. Anyway so I've followed the docs and I can use 'nodetool status' to test and make sure all the nodes are up - so far so good.

Then I login to the seed node and start cqlsh and try and create the keyspace and everything goes pear shaped and Im not sure why. The cqlsh doesn't throw any errors but all the nodes appear to remain at 0.0% and nothing works, but the moment I drop the keyspace and test table they come back up to some normal value. I would really appreciate if someone could point out what Im doing wrong.

These are the statements I use for my keyspace and schema:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE testSpace WITH REPLICATION = {'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1' : 1};
CREATE TABLE testSpace.TestDB (name varchar, salary int, PRIMARY KEY (name));
```

At this point there are no errors thrown, but doing a select * on the table yields "Unable to complete request: one or more nodes were unavailable."

```
cqlsh:testSpace> select * from TestDB  ;
Unable to complete request: one or more nodes were unavailable.
```

Could someone please tell me what I've messed up with please?

My network properties files is as follows, and Im using the 'RackInferringSnitch':

```
10.1.10.100=DC1:RAC1
10.1.10.101=DC1:RAC1
10.1.10.102=DC1:RAC1
```

Thanks for looking into this and appreciate any info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if anyone is interested - I solved this by changing the snitch to PropertiesFileSnitch and deleted all the old data and restarted cassandra and things worked seamlessly.

If anyone can shed some light as to why RackInferringSnitch didn't work that'd be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

When you use the RackInferringSnitch, the topology of the network is inferred by the octet of the node's IP address. You used the data center name DC1. You needed to use the second octet number of your node IP for the data center name when creating the keyspace. For example, 100 would be the name of the data center for node 110.100.200.105. Looks like this "how to" info about the keyspace was dropped from the docs by mistake.